# Changing the default font does not work

Tags: android, fonts, default, typeface

```
<TextView ... android:typeface = "monospace" />
```

This doesn't show any change in the IDE editor or in my phone.
I cant use all the default fonts, It doesn't work.
All the other attributes are working except typeface. 
I reinstalled android studio but it didn't solve the problem.
Please let me what should I do.

Comment: Post your question in detail in order to get best answers

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to change your font, go to your XML file add statement

```
android:fontFamily ="sans-serif"
```

Comment: Thank you It WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!! But still what I don't understand is that I could change the font with typeface in my desktop. This problem only happens in my laptop. But again, Thanks!

Comment: Your most welcome...If it helped could you accept the answer..would appreciate it